# How to delete comment which a deeply nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB. This is a MERN project. I am using the MongoDB database. I am trying to delete the comments using id which are nested in an array of objects. My document looks like this,

```
{
    "_id": "60aa8ed98ad79d380cb250b4",
    "course_id": "609a2cedd07ba73200ada318",
    "instructor_id": "609a2875aeefe40a6c9befc5",
    "title": "New Annoucement",
    "description": "new announcement is posted",
    "video_url": "youtube.com",
    "comments": [
        {
            "comments": [
                {
                    "comments": [
                        {
                            "comments": [
                                {
                                    "comments": [],
                                    "_id": "60aa912b301ccc397057ded6",
                                    "username": "Sandy",
                                    "user_id": "609a2875aeefe40a6c9befc5",
                                    "content": "1",
                                    "parentId": "60aa9123301ccc397057ded5",
                                    "type": "reply",
                                    "annoucementId": "60aa8ed98ad79d380cb250b4"
                                }
                            ],
                            "_id": "60aa9123301ccc397057ded5",
                            "username": "Sandy",
                            "user_id": "609a2875aeefe40a6c9befc5",
                            "content": "why its not deleting",
                            "parentId": "60aa8f648ad79d380cb250b6",
                            "type": "reply",
                            "annoucementId": "60aa8ed98ad79d380cb250b4"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "60aa8f648ad79d380cb250b6",
                    "username": "Sandy",
                    "user_id": "609a2875aeefe40a6c9befc5",
                    "content": "two",
                    "parentId": "60aa8edd8ad79d380cb250b5",
                    "type": "reply",
                    "annoucementId": "60aa8ed98ad79d380cb250b4"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "60aa8edd8ad79d380cb250b5",
            "username": "Sandy",
            "user_id": "609a2875aeefe40a6c9befc5",
            "content": "one",
            "type": "comment",
            "annoucementId": "60aa8ed98ad79d380cb250b4"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-05-23T17:20:25.579Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-05-23T17:30:19.116Z",
    "__v": 6
}
```

this is a big object called announcements which has a comments array and that contains an array of objects which are comments. And if someone replies to a comment I am making another array called comments and storing all the replies objects.
I want to delete the object using ._id: 60aa912b301ccc397057ded6, which is the reply object with the content "1".

I have tried to find, findById, findOneAndRemove, findOneAndDelete it's not finding the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps change the way you structure the comments and not nest them? Since each comment already has a unique id, nesting them only makes it more difficult to access the comment object, and it's a rabbit's hole, where the nesting might never end?

I propose you add an property in the comment object A to point to other comment object B, if A is a reply or quote of B.

That way you can have an array of comment objects and modify them must easily.

Cheers.

Comment: But this is working fine now I figured out on how to delete it in a nested one. But does my way of implementation reduces performance if it scales although it is just a project? I am using for loop to find and delete.